# How to limit user for storing data in Parse and check for registered devices

Tags: objective-c, database, parse-platform

I have a classes with many Users, Devices and urls class which stores each users, username, device name and some urls.

If user Suleman login to my app in iPhone 4, Class will contain his User ID and Iphone 4. If a same user Suleman Login to my app in iPad, class will now contain User ID and his iPhone 4 and iPad. After that user send some url to my url class from ipad and iphone.

**My first question:**

1. how can I put check on that user can not register same iphone 4 many
   times. Register device id only one time.
2. How can I check that user can only store 5 urls for each device. If
       user try to send 6th url, it will not store and my app will say that
       you have reached your limited data.

Thanks in advance... Completely new in Parse and iOS development. Or any better way for this.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you need some way to always know exactly who it is that is accessing your software on a device. You can't trust the user will always use the same username and you can't trust an IP address.

I would propose using an email address.

Make them enter in their email to register a device and send them a confirmation code/link. That way you can track their usage across applications and limit their access/how many devices they can register.

Comment: Thanks for the idea... One more question, how can my app on iphone know that ipad just updated mysql database on server... so it can execute some code to get data from server?

Comment: You would have to set up polling to query the database on intervals. Be careful to not set the interval too low or your mobile users will be upset. =)